# Injecting ajax into a jQuery popunder

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have been given the task of updating a clients popunders. The former system was written by the client and is starting to produce undesirable results.

We elected to use a jQuery popunder found on [GitHub](https://github.com/hpbuniat/jquery-popunder).

With this in hand I started putting together a test page for this popunder method (the link driven example).

The problem I am running into is with getting the ajax call injected into the popunder itself.

```js
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'ajax.php',
  dataType: "jsonp",
  data: {
    mocc: mocc
  },

  success: function(result) {

    alert(data)
    if (result.error === true) {

    } else {
      if (result.method == 'popunder') {
        createPopunderLink(result.url, result.width, result.height);
      }
    }
  },

  error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
 /* Code removed due to client confidentiality */
  }
});
```

```html
<body>

  <a href="#" onclick="$.popunder()">Test Link</a>




  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $('form[action="#"]').attr('action', document.location.href);
      $(window.aPopunder = [
        ['http://www.wikipedia.org']
      ]).each(function(i, e) {
        eval(e.innerHTML);
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

Thoughts?

Comment: `thoughts`? ..  annoying thing to do in the first place

Comment: Much like responding to a question with condescension is an annoying thing to do.